# Programmatically re-creating "kill -3" in Java (especially locked monitors)

Tags: java

I need to capture the list of monitors locked by the current thread and dump it into a file. The only functionality that does something similar is `kill -3` command to Java VM. Is there a way to do the same thing programmatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A variety of useful information about a running JVM and things in it are available from `java.lang.management` beans.
Call [ThreadMXBean.getThreadInfo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/ThreadMXBean.html#getThreadInfo(long[],%20boolean,%20boolean))
on the bean obtained within the same JVM from `ManagementFactory` then `.getLockedMonitors()` and format and write as you wish. 
From outside the JVM you can access these beans with JMX-RMI (with the same userid on the same machine, or various authentication options on a remote machine) but the current thread might change between one access and the next; 
you're probably better off getting *all* threads with `.dumpAllThreads()` and then finding the one you want in the array.